# Bayesian Learning: Finding the variance of noise

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, estimators, learning

Suppose $x_i \sim N(10,4)$ - ie, the distribution is known.

There is a noisy signal $s_i \sim N(x_i, \sigma_e^2)$ and I want to estimate $\sigma_e$.

I see some pairs ($s_i, x_i$) but they are not 'random' (there is some selection on $s_i$ - say, I see these values mostly for large values of $s_i$).

What approach would you recommend for estimating $\sigma_e$?

My first thought was to simply take $\hat\sigma_e = \sqrt{\sum(s_i-x_i)^2/N}$ but I think this would be wrong since my data contains mostly larger $s_i$?

I next tried to model the distribution of $x_i | s_i$. The Bayesian posterior distribution is
$N((\frac{\sigma_{e}^2}{\sigma_{e}^2+4})10 + (\frac{4}{\sigma_{e}^2+4})s_{i},  \frac{\sigma_{e}^2*4}{\sigma_{e}^2+4})$
where the $4$ and $10$ come from the distribution of $x_i$ above.

But I do not know how to proceed. I believe that the difference between the expected value of $x_i|s_i$ and the actual observed value should be informative of $\sigma_e$ somehow, but I am confused since $\sigma_e$ enters both the expected value term and the variance term above. Trying to find the MLE by differentiating the log likelihood above becomes very complicated. Is there something obvious that I am missing? Or any approach that you would recommend to estimate $\sigma_e$?

Edit: To be clear, I know that there is selection on $s_i$, but I am sure that there is no selection of $x_i$ or $x_i|s_i$.

So I feel $x_i|s_i$ should be informative about $\sigma_e$ (For instance, if I only see $x_i$ very close to $s_i$ for each $s_i$, I know that $\sigma_e$ is small; but if I see $x_i|s_i \sim N(10,4)$ (ie, close to the original distribution) I would believe that $\sigma_e$ is large. How can I formalize this intuition to form an estimator?

Edit2: Consider $a_i = \frac{x_i-s_i}{10-s_i}$

$E[a_i|s_i] = E[\frac{x_i-s_i}{10-s_i} | s_i]$

$= \frac{E[x_i | s_i] - s_i}{10-s_i}$

From the equation above, I know that $E[x_i | s_i] = (\frac{\sigma_{e}^2}{\sigma_{e}^2+4})10 + (\frac{4}{\sigma_{e}^2+4})s_{i}$

Therefore, $E[a_i|s_i] = \frac{\sigma_{e}^2}{\sigma_{e}^2+4}$.

1. Is this correct? If yes, can I take the mean of $[a_i|s_i]$ as an estimator of $\frac{\sigma_{e}^2}{\sigma_{e}^2+4}$? This should overcome the selection problem, since there is no selection *conditional* on an $s_i$.
2. Can I get an estimate of $\sigma_{e}^2$ by making it the subject of the formula in 1. above?

Any help, even directional, would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If $\frac1N\sum(s_i-x_i)$ is close to $0$ and roughly half the $s_i < x_i$ then you may not have a problem.  Alternatively, if you think you are only seeing $s_i$ above some threshold and are seeing all such $s_i$ then there may be a possibility.  But otherwise I so not see a satisfactory approach

Comment: @Henry Thanks! That expression is significantly greater than 0, and there is no clean threshold for $s_i$ (just that, *mostly*, larger values are selected). 
The conditional distribution of $x_i|s_i$ should overcome the selection issue, right? Is there any convenient way of estimating $\sigma_e$ from that?

Comment: I don't think you have much hope unless you have some method for characterizing the missingness distribution as a function of $s_i$?

Comment: @CliffAB You are possibly right, but I am not able to see exactly why. For instance, even if I have 1 $s_i$ but multiple corresponding $x_i$, shouldn't the conditional distribution of $x_i | s_i$ be informative about $\sigma_e$? Or am I just being dense? 
Thanks!

Comment: Not if some other $x_i$ corresponding to that $s_i$ are missing but not independently of $x_i$, if you do not know which ones or why

Comment: @Henry That I am sure of - there is no selection on $x_i$ or $x_i|s_i$. Only on $s_i$. Is there any convenient estimator in this case?

Comment: When the sample is random, subtracting $4^2$ from the mean squared residual (the average of the $(x_i-10)^2$) estimates $\sigma_e^2.$  But when there's only some vague "selection" method you can't conclude *anything.*

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. But as I wrote in the earlier comment, I am not able to see exactly why. For instance, even if I have 1 $s_i$  but multiple corresponding $x_i$, shouldn't the conditional distribution of $x_i | s_i$ be informative about $\sigma_e$? I know that, while there is a selection on $s_i$, there is no selection on $x_i$ or $x_i | s_i$

Comment: The problem is that the results are likely to be biased and it's difficult to see how the bias could be corrected without knowing more about the selection process.  You could make progress with very little information.  For instance, if only values of $s_i$ exceeding some threshold are taken and you know what fraction have been dropped, a decent estimate looks possible.  *Some* estimate is possible even without knowing that fraction: the threshold becomes a "nuisance parameter" in the model.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much for your patience so far! But I am still not sure why taking the conditional distribution of $x_i | s_i$ does not overcome the selection problem. It is very likely I am just being stupid, but could I request you to look at edit2 above and let me know where that logic breaks down? Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, the title is confusing: you are asking about estimating the variance of the *noise,* not the signal.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to address two questions: (1) demonstrating that how the data are selected does matter for estimation and (2) suggesting how to estimate the parameter.

Everything flows from the joint distribution.  So--choosing a unit of measurement in which the Normally distributed variable $X$ (representing the $x_i$) has zero mean and unit variance, the joint distribution of $(S,X)$ (where $S$ represents $s_i$) is Bivariate Normal with density given by the product of the density of $X$ and the conditional density of $S,$

$$f_{S,X}(s,x;\sigma) = f_{S\mid X}(s;\sigma)f_X(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(s-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,\mathrm ds\mathrm dx.$$

The only parameter, to be estimated, is $\sigma.$  (It is the ratio of the error standard deviation to the standard deviation of $X.$)

The twist is that we don't have a random sample from this distribution.  Instead, some unspecified "selection" was used to choose observations from this distribution with probabilities determined by $S.$  This can be stated mathematically in terms of those selection probabilities: namely, let the chance of keeping an observation $(s_i,x_i)$ be $p = p(s_i),$ a function depending on $s_i.$  This makes the probability density equal to

$$f_{S,X}(s,x;\sigma,p) = C(\sigma,p)\,p(s)f_{S,X}(s,x;\sigma)$$

where $C(\sigma,p)$ is the normalizing constant.

Consider the log likelihood of such a sample $((s_i,x_i),i=1,\ldots, n)$ of $n$ selected observations.  It is the sum

$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{i=1}^n \log f_{S,X}(s,x;\sigma,p) \\
&=n\log C(\sigma,p) - \frac{n}{2}\left(\log(2\pi) + 2 \log \sigma\right) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{(s_i-x_i)^2}{\sigma^2}+x_i^2\right) + \sum_{i=1}^n \log p(s_i)  .
\end{aligned}$$

Because we haven't specified $p,$ we don't know $C(\sigma,p),$ so there's nothing we can do to analyze the log likelihood.  *We cannot proceed without information about $p.$*

**Consider the case where $p$ is constant.**  That implies the normalization constant does not depend on $\sigma,$ giving the usual maximum likelihood estimate

$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (s_i-x_i)^2.$$

**Now suppose $p(s)=1$ when $s\ge T$ and $p(s)=0$ otherwise.**  That is, you select only values of $s_i$ exceeding some specified threshold $T.$  The normalization constant is the reciprocal of the chance that $S\ge T,$ given by $\Phi(-T/\sqrt{1+\sigma^2})$ where $\Phi$ is the standard Normal CDF.  Differentiating the log likelihood w.r.t. $\sigma$ and equating it with zero to find critical points now gives

$$0 = n \frac{\sigma T}{(1+\sigma^2)^{3/2}} \frac{\phi(-T/\sqrt{1+\sigma^2})}{\Phi(-T/\sqrt{1+\sigma^2})} - \frac{n}{\sigma} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(s_i-x_i)^2}{\sigma^3}\tag{*}$$

(This requires numerical solution.  I found it works well to multiply the r.h.s. by $\sigma^3/n,$ thereby avoiding some of the divisions that can cause problems near $\sigma=0.$)

As $T\to-\infty,$ the first term in $(*)$ makes a vanishingly small contribution and the (unique) solution closely approximates $\hat \sigma.$  But for larger (especially positive) values of $T,$ this solution is nearly unbiased and far superior to $\hat\sigma.$  Here, for example, is a simulation of $200$ samples of $(S,X),$ each with approximately $n=100$ selected values, where $\sigma=1$ and $T=3.$  In each sample the solution to $(*)$ (the MLE) is plotted horizontally and the root mean square difference $\hat\sigma,$ plotted vertically, is consistently biased about 25% low:

[image]

**This starkly shows the effect on the native estimator $\hat \sigma$ of selecting the observations based on the values of $s_i.$**  Evidently, a more complex procedure described by a general function $p$ will likely exhibit a comparable bias.

Generally, this bias will increase with both $T/\sigma$ and $\sigma.$  For instance, for $\sigma \approx 1/4$ and $T=4\sigma=1,$ the estimator $\hat\sigma$ is biased only a few percent low.  Thus, when the noise is not too great compared to the variation in the signal, you likely have little to worry about and could use $\hat\sigma$ to estimate its standard deviation.

This little example also shows that maximum likelihood estimation is likely to work: it certainly does the job here with relatively small samples and a stringent cutoff threshold (only one in every $59$ random observations will pass this threshold).

**We can go further and be more general** even if we make broader assumptions about $p.$  For instance, we might suppose there is an *unknown* selection threshold $T.$  Now this must be estimated along with $\sigma,$ giving a two-parameter problem where $0\lt \sigma$ and $-\infty \lt T \le \min(s_i).$  That latter condition indicates the solution can sometimes be $\hat T = \min(s_i),$ a value on the boundary of the parameter space, so take some care in seeking solutions and applying the standard theorems of maximum likelihood (many of which fail to hold for boundary solutions).

Comment: Thank you! This answer is very helpful, and incredibly detailed. 
You say that I need to know the joint distribution to be able to estimate $\sigma$, and conclude that 'We cannot proceed without information about p'. I still do not understand why this is the case - but thanks to your approach, I have been able to proceed with the MLE estimator based on the distribution of $x_i|s_i$. (I have added it as a separate answer). I am able to recover $\sigma$ even without knowing p, which contradicts your conclusion. Could you please check my answer and see if you agree, or point out the error in it?

Comment: I offered two examples with differing $p,$ showing how $\hat\sigma$ thereby changes.  That demonstrates you *cannot* estimate $\sigma$ accurately without some information about $p,$ unless by a matter of luck your estimator happens to be the one appropriate for your $p.$

Comment: But I am able to recover the true $\sigma$ fairly accurately, even for a wide range of $p$ (threshold $T$ varying from 2 to 10) in my answer below - so it should not be the case that it was just luck. It also intuitively makes sense because the conditional distribution of $x_i|s_i$ (which I use for my estimator) is independent of $p$. If you still disagree, can you let me know where exactly the logic in my answer breaks down? Thanks!

Comment: You have explored only a very tiny subset of the parameter space, in a region where the selection doesn't matter.  I discussed that in my answer.  The problems occur when $\sigma$ is comparable to or larger than the variance of $X$ and $T$ is several times greater than $\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)+\sigma^2}.$

Comment: In my answer, variance of $X$ is 1, and $\sigma$ ranges from 3 to 15 - so it satisfies the conditions pointed out in your answer where the problems should occur. Also, for $\sigma = 3$, $T$ ranges upto 10, which is ~3x times that expression.

Comment: Well, you are obtaining results starkly different from those I did, which is why I am suspicious.  Your estimator appears to be exactly what I have called $\hat\sigma.$

Comment: No - my estimator is very different from your $\hat{\sigma}$ - I have used the conditional distribution of $x_i|s_i$ - so $\sigma$ also enters the expectation term (not just the variance term), and the LL has no easy analytic expression.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the approach outlined in whuber's answer (Thanks!). Considering the case where $x_i \sim N(0,1)$ (equivalent to the original problem, but with simpler algebra), I know that the *conditional* distribution of $x_i | s_i \sim N(\frac{s_{i}}{\sigma_{e}^2+1},  \frac{\sigma_{e}^2}{\sigma_{e}^2+1})$.

Crucially, this distribution is *conditional* on $s_i$ and hence does not suffer from the selection problem.

I can write this conditional density using the normal formula, which gives the log likelihood:
$LL = \sum[-0.5log(\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}) -\frac{(x\sigma^2+x-s)^2}{2\sigma^2(\sigma^2+1)}] $

I maximize this log likelihood using numeric methods to get $\sigma$.

I simulated this using different values for $\sigma$ and different filtering thresholds (ie, keeping only those $s_i$ which exceed a threshold $T$) and am able to recover the original $\sigma$ quite well.
[[image: True vs estimated <span class=]$\sigma$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c04r.png)

So I can recover the true parameter value, even without knowledge of the selection criteria.